# BinaryTree cannot delete the root node

Tags: c

Sorry, I encountered a problem when writing a binary tree deletion program.

When I insert a root node and delete it or delete to the last node, the program will get stuck.

I have read my code several times carefully, but I still can’t find any errors.

I did write a method to delete the root node, and tried various ways of writing.

But when the program is compiled and executed, it will pause and stop the progra.

I would like to ask everyone, how should I modify.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *back;
    struct tree *Left;
    struct tree *Right;
};
struct tree *root=NULL;

struct tree *binary_tree(struct tree *,int );
void deletion(int );
struct tree * search(int );
void preorder(struct tree *);




int main(){
    int op;
    int num0,num;
    int dnum;
    while(1){
        printf("[1] Add [2] Delete [0] Exit:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        if(op==1){
            printf("Insert a number:");
                scanf("%d",&num0);
                if(num0==0){
                    break;
                }else{
                    num=num0;
                    root=binary_tree(root,num);
                }
        }else if(op==2){
            printf("Delete a number:");
            scanf("%d",&dnum);
            deletion(dnum);
        }else if(op==0){
            break;
        }
        printf("Preorder:");
        preorder(root);
        printf("\n----------------------\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

struct tree *binary_tree(struct tree *root,int num){
    struct tree *current;
    struct tree *backup;
    struct tree *newnode=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(newnode!=NULL){
        newnode->data=num;
        newnode->back=NULL;
        newnode->Left=NULL;
        newnode->Right=NULL;
    }
    
    if(root==NULL){
        root=newnode;
        return root;
    }else{
        for(current=root;current!=NULL;){
            backup=current;
            if(current->data>num){
                current=current->Left;
            }else if(current->data<num){
                current=current->Right;
            }else{
                printf("%d already exit.\n",current->data);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(backup->data>num){
            backup->Left=newnode;
            newnode->back=backup;
        }else if(backup->data<num){
            backup->Right=newnode;
            newnode->back=backup;
        }else{
            free(newnode);
        }   
        return root;
    }
}


void deletion(int del_num){
    struct tree *del=search(del_num);
    if(del==NULL){
        printf("%d  does not exist in the tree.\n",del_num);
    }else if(del->Left==NULL&&del->Right==NULL){   //Deleted value is a leafnode 
        if(del->back->Right==del){  // the leafnode of right subtree  
            del->back->Right = NULL; 
            free(del);
        }else if(del->back->Left==del){ //the leafnode of left subtree
            del->back->Left = NULL; 
            free(del);  
        }else{      //Deleted value is a leafnode and root node
            root=NULL;
            del=NULL;
            free(del);
        }   
    }else if(del->Right!=NULL&&del->Left==NULL||del->Right==NULL&&del->Left!=NULL){ //Only one side of the deleted value has subtrees
        if(del->Right!=NULL){   //Only right subtree
            if(del->back==NULL){    //Deleted value is the root node
                root=del->Right;
                root->back=NULL;
                free(del);
            }else if(del->back!=NULL&&del->Right!=NULL){    //The right node of the parent node
                del->back->Right=del->Right;
                del->Right->back=del->back;
                free(del);
            }
        }else if(del->Left!=NULL){  //Only left subtree
            if(del->back==NULL){    //Deleted value is the root node
                root=del->Left;
                root->back=NULL;
                free(del);
            }else if(del->back!=NULL&&del->Left!=NULL){     //The left node of the parent node      
                del->back->Left=del->Left;
                del->Left->back=del->back; 
            }
        }

    }else{      
            if(del->Left!=NULL&&del->Right!=NULL){  //The deleted value has both left and right subtrees
                struct tree *temp;
                temp=del->Left;
                if(temp->Right==NULL){  //If the left child node has no right node
                    del->data=temp->data;
                    if(temp->Left!=NULL){   
                        temp->Left->back=del;
                        del->Left=temp->Left;
                        free(temp); 
                    }else{  //If the left child node of temp is empty 
                        del->Left=NULL;
                        free(temp);
                    }
                    
                }else{  //If the left child node has a right node
                    while(temp->Right!=NULL){
                        temp=temp->Right;
                    }
                        del->data=temp->data;
                        if(temp->Left!=NULL){
                            temp->back->Right=temp->Left;
                            temp->Left->back=temp->back;
                            free(temp);
                        }else{  //If the left child node of temp is empty 
                            temp->back->Right=NULL;
                            free(temp);
                        }
                        
                }

            }
             
    }
    
}

struct tree *search(int del_num){
    struct tree *del=root;
    while(del!=NULL){
        if(del->data>del_num){
            del=del->Left;
        }else if(del->data<del_num){
            del=del->Right;
        }else{  //Find the value to be deleted 
            return del;
        }
    }   
    return NULL;
}


void preorder(struct tree *ptr){
    if(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        preorder(ptr->Left);
        preorder(ptr->Right);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you ran it line by line on a debugger to see what’s happening? If it never ends, that’s the best way to figure out what’s happening.

Comment: Yes, I have gradually tried various situations of deleting nodes but it only has problems when deleting the root node.
The program will be forcibly stopped, and the root node has not been deleted.

Comment: So what did you learn while going through line by line when deleting that one and observing the flow and variables?

Comment: I try to point the root node (root) and (del) to NULL and release del